# When scaling vertices from an svg to 0 on the x so they are all lined up, it does not put them on the same position

Tags: cycles-render-engine, vertices, transforms, artifacts, svg

I have imported a svg to blender and converted it to a mesh.

I am trying to set all vertices on the same y position by scaling all to 0 on the y like you would normally do with a mesh created in blender.

Normally it would work with a mesh made in blender but for some reason any SVG imported has very very small differences in vertex depth. I think that the problems is because the number is so low (differences of -0.000027 to -0.0000034)etc the scale to 0 can not calculate the numbers for some reason.

I am trying to do this because when viewed at an angle when rendered in cycles, because of these very small differences it is causing artifacts to show. It believe it also has to do with cycles too because when I render the same object in EEVEE there are no artifacts.

Any advise on how to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, what's the overall scale or dimensions of your object ?

Comment: Scale is 1. I reset it after scaling up. The real size of the object is about 50x50mm.